# How to get the starting x position and ending x position in Unity?

Tags: javascript, c#, unity-game-engine

I cannot find any similar question, please do let me know if I'm using wrong wording or missing any similar resolved question.

How can I get the starting point (x,y) and ending point (x,y) of a GameObject relative to the screen? 
So, if my object's x starts from 10 and end at 20 how can I determine the values in unity C# or even if you only know it in Javascript.

Please let me know if you need more details.
Thank in advance.

Comment: So is this a 2d project?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I was able to get the correct values by following method. Please let me know if any one want me to explain it.

```
    orbitScroller = GameObject.Find("OrbitScroll").transform;
    RectTransform rt = orbitScroller.GetComponent<RectTransform>();
    float objWidth = rt.rect.width;
    float objHheight = rt.rect.height;
    x = orbitScroller.position.x - (objWidth / 2);
    xx = orbitScroller.position.x + (objWidth / 2);

    y = orbitScroller.position.y - (objHheight / 2 );
    yy = orbitScroller.position.y + (objHheight / 2);
```

x = starting point

xx = ending point

same with 'y'

Working perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

You can access these values in a script attached to the gameobject.

```
transform.position.x  //starting x point
transform.position.y  //starting y point
transform.position.x + transform.lossyScale.x  //ending x point
transform.position.y + transform.lossyScale.y  //ending y point
```